# Cannot set up audiences containing members of a AD Group on SharePoint 2007

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am having a problem where in SharePoint 2007 after verifying the profile import was successful and the AD group is there, I go to audiences and try to create a rule where the user must be a member of said AD group. The problem is that when i get to the point of searching for the group to set up the rule, SharePoint can't find that group or any other for that matter. It just comes up with "TEMPLATE" which is not in AD.

Is there a fix for this issue? Or any suggestions on something to try to get SharePoint to find groups when setting up rules for Audiences?

### UPDATE:

I found that we had two connections to our Active Directory, one pulling users and one pulling groups.  I removed the groups, re ran the full import and removed all of the profiles that were not imported.  Then i went back and tried to set up the Audience again and it worked!!

Not sure what happened or why telling SharePoint to import groups caused Audience to fail, anyone have an answer or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved this issue by removing one of the Active Directory Connections (the one that was supposed to import groups) and the Audience was able to pull ***some*** groups and users.  After changing the '***Owner***' of the specific audience, I was able to finish creating the Audience where everyone that was supposed to be in it, was.  If the owner is the 'System account' and not specifically on your companies domain, the Audience will not find 100% of the users it is supposed to.  Weird, but thats Microsoft for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, multiple connections to the same AD is not supported...see the comment below:
Currently we only support "one AD-Connection per Domain and Forest" at a same time! You must configure the entire connection for all OU's and objects you want to import(or export like the thumbnailPhoto) within the same domain and forest on one single AD-connection! Multiple connections to the same Domain and forest at a same time are simply not working!

Example:
You have configured an AD-Connection to your Domain "MyCompany" by chosen the OU's for "NA-Users", "EU-User" and some others. Later on you decide to add another AD-Connection against the same Domain but now having only for a specific OU within the same forest to use the "Export profile picture from SharePoint to AD"

Result:
You'll not get any pictures updated on the AD as this does simply not work. You must change the previous created AD-connection and modifying the property mapping and/or adding additional OU's to be synced within "one single AD-Connection".

THE LINK IS - http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2010/09/20/user-profile-sync-sharepoint-2010.aspx